# how to get short/netbios name of trusted domain

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I have a user object from Active Directory that has properties like distinguished name. I can easily get the domain portion from that, like dc=somedomain,dc=com. If it were the local domain, I could use Powershell: (get-addomain -Identity "dc=mydomain,dc=com").netbiosname to get the short name. But for this external trusted domain, that doesn't work because it just searches within the local domain. Does anyone know of another way to use Powershell to get the short name for the domain of an arbitrary AD user/group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but this is a quicker way:

```
$Domain = 'sometrusteddomain.com'
$NetbiosName = (get-adtrust -filter {Name -eq $Domain} -Properties FlatName).FlatName
```

Comment: This solution also does not require the computer running the command to have direct access to the domain controller of the trusted domain. I suppose it contacts its own domain controller to get the info. But, it only works for a foreign trusted domain, not local domain.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the `-Server` argument to your `Get-ADDomain` call that specifies a DC in that forest.  If you were on a non-domain joined machine, you could add `-Credential` to explicitly provide credentials as well. But hypothetically, your trust will pass along your current credentials automatically.

So the new command would look like this:

```
(Get-ADDomain 'dc=mydomain,dc=com' -Server 'dc.mydomain.com').NetBIOSName
```

You can also combine it with `Get-ADDomainController` if you don't already know a DC for the target domain.

```
$dc = (Get-ADDomainController -Discover -DomainName mydomain.com).HostName[0]
(Get-ADDomain 'dc=mydomain,dc=com' -Server $dc).NetBIOSName
```